# Horror movie, father rescuing son from world found behind a mirror

Tags: identify-this-movie, horror, thriller

The scene depicts a father, who I believe has a shotgun slung around his back, searching for his son in what I believe is a house.  He hears his son calling for him, shouting for help.  The son's shouts for help sounded weird, as if he were a ghost.

The father hears his son through a bathroom mirror.  The father opens the mirror cabinet and closes it, to no avail.  He then sees a nearby painting, depicting his son stuck and shouting in horror in the same bathroom mirror.  A window is beside this painted mirror, through which he frantically reaches behind the mirror and feels nothing but the outside wall. The father has an idea and breaks the mirror, revealing another world full of darkness, except for a small light emitting from a pool of water and a cage with his son in it.

This location is a few stories down, and the father climbs down with rope.  My memory fails here and I only remember that he jumps into the pool with his son, being chased by a humanoid monster.  He swims down and then back up, where he ends up in the "real world" swimming pool.  The monster then slowly comes up out of the water behind them...this is where my memory ends.

This may very well be a network movie and I believe this movie was on cable before the year 2000.

Answer (score 10):

Your recollection matches a section of the [IMDb synopsis](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0091223/synopsis) for *House* (1986).  There are too many details to quote it all, but it mentions the father seeing his son behind a mirror in a painting, breaking the real mirror, entering "another dimension" where there is water, rescuing his son from monsters and emerging through a swimming pool.

Comment: This is the film I was going to suggest. Sounds like a match to me.