Horror movie about a child disappearing in a pool?
A long time ago (many years) I watched a horror movie I can't find. I will write about every detail I remember!
I think a family moved to a new house because the father was a writer? So their little boy was playing in the backyard and he disappeared in the pool. He was lost for a long time but then as the movie progressed, the father (or mother, sorry I'm not sure) was in the bathroom and there was a rag in front of the mirror. 
He removed the rag and he saw a sign in the mirror, which gave him the clue as to where the boy was! He removed the mirror and there was a gap like a tunnel going down. It was all black. 
It's difficult for me to remember everything and make sense out of it, but there was some kind of military/soldier theme in the movie too (like, old memories of the father).
Years between 1990-2005. It was in colour, English, probably US.

Nevermind, I believe I found it! I saw this thread: https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/11358/horror-movie-father-rescuing-son-from-world-found-behind-a-mirror Turns out this is the movie!
